# Struts 2 only displaying one row from mysql table on JSP using s:iterator

Tags: struts2

I'm getting a very strange problem with struts 2, I am using s:iterator to pull in a list of questions, however when I use the s:property tag, only the ID will be displayed and nothing else. There are 4 columns, id, groupid, subgroupid and questiontxt yet I can only seem to be able to display the ID. I tested the list, and it contains all the columns, it has saved them properly from the database, but the only thing I am able to display on screen is ID.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<link href=<s:url value="resources/welcome.css" /> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

    enter code here

<body>
    <table>
        <s:iterator value="listQuestionsBasic" var="question">
        <tr>        
        <td>
        <s:property value="#question.id" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <s:property value="#question.groupid" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <s:property value="#question.subgroupid" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <s:property value="#question.questiontxt" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by renaming the variables according to proper java etiquette, IE questiontxt column as String questionTxt, not String questiontxt.

I need a beer.